# Selecting posts, user details and votes from 3 MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a **user** table with id, username, email etc..

**post** table with id, uid (user id), content etc and

**vote** table with id, uid, pid (post id), vote (ENUM : '1' and '-1').

In the vote column of Vote table, 1 represents up vote and -1 represents down vote.

I wish to select ten posts with user details and no of upvotes and downvotes. I tried it with the following table but it doesn't work. It gives redundant result for some ids.

```
select 
    p.id,
    p.uid,
    p.post,
    u.username,
    count(puv.pid) as upvotes,
    group_concat(puv.uid) upvoteIds,
    count(pdv.pid) as downvotes,
    group_concat(pdv.uid) downvoteIds
from
    posts p
        join
    user u ON u.id = p.uid
        left join
    postvotes puv ON puv.pid = p.id and puv.vote = '1'
        left join
    postvotes pdv ON pdv.pid = p.id and pdv.vote = '-1'
where
    p.deleted = 0
group by u.username , p.created , p.post , p.id , p.uid
order by p.created DESC
limit 0 , 10
```

Result of the query:

```
+----+-----+--------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| id | uid |  post  | username | upvotes | upvoteIds | downvotes | downvoteIds |
+----+-----+--------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| 19 | 2   | Post 1 | john     | 2       | 3,3       | 2         | 1,2         |
| 18 | 1   | Post 2 | dinesh   | 2       | 3,1       | 0         | NULL        |
| 17 | 3   | Post 3 | sudeep   | 0       | NULL      | 1         | 3           |
+----+-----+--------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
```

The first row gives duplicate ids for **upvoteIds** and **upvotes** as 2. Here, upvotes should be 1 since post with id 19 has only 1 upvote. Have a look at the following **votes** table:

```
+----+-----+-----+------+
| id | pid | uid | vote |
+----+-----+-----+------+
| 1  | 19  | 3   | 1    |
| 2  | 18  | 3   | 1    |
| 3  | 17  | 3   | -1   |
| 4  | 19  | 1   | -1   |
| 5  | 18  | 1   | 1    |
| 6  | 19  | 2   | -1   |
+----+-----+-----+------+
```

**UPDATE**

Table **Posts**

```
+----+-----+--------+
| id | uid |  post  |
+----+-----+--------+
| 17 | 3   | post 3 |
| 18 | 1   | post 2 |
| 19 | 2   | post 1 |
+----+-----+--------+
```

Comment: Can you add a SQLFiddle?

Comment: Can you post the data of other tables also

Comment: Added the post table data. User table has the general id, username, email fields that you'd expect.

Comment: Understood. How to get it right?

Comment: What is the significance of the uid column on the post table? Is that the author of the post?

Comment: Ok, so are you trying to get the user details of the author of the post or the user details of the voter?

Comment: user details of the author of the post. Consider this, I'm trying to select posts, the author details of the post along with the no of upvotes and downvotes for each post in one query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always recommend starting with the table that contains the data that will ultimately need to be grouped, which in this case is the `postvotes` table.

```
# upvotes
SELECT puv.pid, count(puv.vote) as upvote
FROM postvotes puv
WHERE puv.vote = 1
GROUP BY puv.pid
```

This should give you the following data:

```
+-----+--------+
| pid | upvote |
+-----+--------+
| 19  | 1      |
| 18  | 2      |
+-----+--------+

# downvotes
SELECT pdv.pid, count(pdv.vote) as downvote
FROM postvotes pdv
WHERE pdv.vote = -1
GROUP BY pdv.pid
```

This will give you the following data:

```
+-----+----------+
| pid | downvote |
+-----+----------+
| 17  | 1        |
| 19  | 2        |
+-----+----------+
```

Now, to get them together in one query:

```
SELECT pv.pid, uv.upvote, dv.downvote
FROM postvotes pv
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT puv.pid, count(puv.vote) as upvote
    FROM postvotes puv
    WHERE puv.vote = 1
    GROUP BY puv.pid
) uv
ON pv.pid = uv.pid
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT pdv.pid, count(pdv.vote) as downvote
    FROM postvotes pdv
    WHERE pdv.vote = -1
    GROUP BY pdv.pid
) dv
ON pv.pid = dv.pid
```

That should yield the following data:

```
+-----+--------+----------+
| pid | upvote | downvote |
+-----+--------+----------+
| 19  | 1      | 2        |
| 18  | 2      | NULL     |
| 17  | NULL   | 1        |
+-----+--------+----------+
```

Now the rest is just joining the post and user tables to get the other data you're after, and adding the other conditions in the where clause e.g.:

```
SELECT p.id, p.uid, p.post, u.username, uv.upvote, dv.downvote
FROM posts p
JOIN users u ON p.uid = u.id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT puv.pid, count(puv.vote) as upvote
    FROM postvotes puv
    WHERE puv.vote = 1
    GROUP BY puv.pid
) uv
ON p.id = uv.pid
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT pdv.pid, count(pdv.vote) as downvote
    FROM postvotes pdv
    WHERE pdv.vote = -1
    GROUP BY pdv.pid
) dv
ON p.id = dv.pid
WHERE p.deleted = 0
ORDER BY p.created DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: Your query made perfect sense. Not only does it work as desired but also it was explained beautifully. Thanks a lot for sparing your time to help and saving mine.